# if-else statement does not execute in Java

Tags: java

Why my if-else statement doesn't execute when `gender == "m"` or `gender == "f"` ?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    do 
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter 'm' for male and 'f' for female child: ");
        String gender = input.next();

        System.out.print("The height of the mother in inches: ");
        int motherHeight = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The height of the father in inches: ");
        int fatherHeight = input.nextInt();

        if(gender == "m") 
        {
            double childHeight = ((motherHeight * 13/12) + fatherHeight) / 2;
            System.out.println(childHeight);
        }
        else if (gender == "f")
        {
            double childHeight = ((fatherHeight * 13/14) + motherHeight) / 2;
            System.out.println(childHeight);
        }


    }

    while(input.hasNext());
```

Comment: You weren't paying attention in your Java 101 lectures :-)

Comment: @StephenC Hahaha Actually It's been while since I took the class so I forgot :D.

Comment: @StephenC I have another question. How can I get the program to keep allowing the user to enter new set of values until the user decides to exit ?

Comment: Your code already does that.  The user simply has to enter ^D (Linux / Mac(?)) or ^Z (Windows)

Comment: No with my code I have to enter any character to keep the loop going. But what I want is after the program computes the `childHeight` immediately   run the loop again.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Have you tried a ^D / ^Z ???

Comment: Thank you. I solved the issue. I just had to use `input.hasNextLine()` instead of using `input.hasNext()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the right way to compare string because you are comparing memory location of the String

**problem**

```
if(gender == "m") //compares memory location of the String will return always false
```

**solution**

```
if(gender.equals("m"))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have another question. How can I get the program to keep  allowing the user to enter new set of values until the user decides to exit ?

Comment: @user3716773 put it in a while loop

Comment: The trick is in the condition.