# How come my if else statements don't execute?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

First of all, I have found two other threads that have similar questions. There problem is that they didn't use the [right equal sign for string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096557/why-are-my-if-else-statements-being-ignored) and not [formatting the if statements correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102593/if-else-statement-does-not-execute-in-java) for their particular problem.

For my assignment, I need to create a game called Pig where the player verses a computer in getting 100 points first in rolling pairs of dice. If the player rolls 1 on one turn, they get no additional points. If the player rolls two 1's, then they lose all their points. I have not coded the computer's turn yet, just focusing on the player. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you very much in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FourFive
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    Pigs myopp = new Pigs();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    final int Round = 20;
    int num1, num2;

    int roundTotal = 0;
    int playerTotal = 0;
    int compTotal = 0;
    int win = 100;
    int turnOver = 1;
    Pigs die1 = new Pigs();
    Pigs die2 = new Pigs();
    String play = "y";
    System.out.println("Type y to play");
    play = scan.nextLine();
```

---

```
    while (play.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {
        for (int roll = 1; roll <= 6; roll++)//Each die has 6 sides
        {
            num1 = die1.roll();//rolls first die
            num2 = die2.roll();//rolls second die
            int points = num1 + num2;// adds dies up to get total for this turn
            System.out.println("You roll " + num1 + " and " + num2);

            if (num1 == 1 || num2 == 1)//If either of the dies roll 1, no points 
                points += 0;
            else if (num1 == 1 && num2 == 1)//if both are 1, lose ALL points
                playerTotal = 0;
            else
                System.out.println("you earned " + points + " this round");

            playerTotal += points; total number of points per round added   
            System.out.println("You have a total of " + playerTotal);


            System.out.println("Type y to play");
            play = scan.nextLine();
      }
    }
 }
}
```

My Output:

```
Type y to play
y
You roll 4 and 2
you earned 6 this round
You have a total of 6
Type y to play
y
You roll 6 and 5
you earned 11 this round
You have a total of 17
Type y to play
y
You roll 1 and 1
You have a total of 19 //total should be 0 because of the two 1's
Type y to play
y
You roll 6 and 3
you earned 9 this round
You have a total of 28
Type y to play
y
You roll 1 and 1
You have a total of 30 //total should be 0 because of the two 1's
Type y to play
y
You roll 6 and 4
you earned 10 this round
You have a total of 40
Type y to play
y
You roll 5 and 2
you earned 7 this round
You have a total of 47
Type y to play
y
You roll 5 and 1
You have a total of 53 //shouldn't add any additional points because of the "1"
Type y to play
```

Comment: If the first condition is true it will never go to the second...

Comment: none of the if else statements are ever executed though

Comment: Apart from the order of the if and else-if checks, you're also assigning points to playerTotal regardless of what happens.

>  playerTotal += points;

This is outside any checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if logic is flawed and a bit redundant. Try this:

```
if (num1 == 1 && num2 == 1) {
    playerTotal = 0;
}
else if (num1 != 1 && num2 != 1) {
    playerTotal += points;
    System.out.println("you earned " + points + " this round");
}
System.out.println("You have a total of " + playerTotal);
```

Comment: I just ran into that mess, thank you for fixing the code

Answer (score 2):

If num1 is 1, then the first if condition takes it.  It will not check the 'else if' condition.  Similarly, if num2 is 1, the if condition takes it.  So put your && condition first.

```
        if (num1 == 1 && num2 == 1)//if both are 1, lose ALL points
            playerTotal = 0;
        else if (num1 == 1 || num2 == 1)//If either of the dies roll 1, no points 
            points += 0;
        else
            System.out.println("you earned " + points + " this round");
```

Comment: He would actually have to set `points = 0` instead of `+=` because he has already summed the dice.